# Colorir a fonte do eixo de um dendrograma no ggplot2 de acordo uma variável categórica

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suponha que eu preciso construir um dendrograma no R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdendro)

ggdendrogram(hclust(dist(iris[, -5]))) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu gráfico está criado, mas eu quero melhorar a visualização dele. Para isso, desejo colorir as labels do eixo x de acordo com os valores presentes em `iris$Species`. Ou seja, quero uma escala de três cores, na qual os IDs 1, 2, ..., 150 ficarão identificados a partir dos valores presentes em `iris$Species`.

Como fazer isso de maneira automatizada?

Comment: Porquê o voto para baixo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `element_text` tem um argumento `color` que apesar de não ser oficialmente vetorizado, funciona com vetores.
Como `Species` é uma coluna da base `iris` de classe `"factor"`, pode ser usada como índice de um vetor de cores.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdendro)

cores <- c("red", "green", "blue")
i_cores <- as.integer(iris$Species)
ggdendrogram(hclust(dist(iris[, -5]))) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = cores[i_cores]))
```

> Warning message:
>   Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not
>   officially supported.
>   Results may be unexpected or may change in
>   future versions of ggplot2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente. Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, mesmo correndo o risco de parar de funcionar no futuro.